# Realm Android can't copyOrUpdate object without primary key

Tags: android, realm

I'm using the following architecture with Realm defining a User who has a list of FavoriteSongs:

```
public class User extends RealmObject { 
    @PrimaryKey
    Long id;
    RealmList<FavoriteSong> favoriteSongs;  
}

public class FavoriteSong extends RealmObject { 
    String label;
    Song song;
}

public class Song extends RealmObject {
    @PrimaryKey
    Long id;
    String title;   
}
```

My app models basically mirrors the server models. So when I receive a new FavoriteSong, I want to save it to the realm:

```
FavoriteSong favoriteSong = ...favorite song from server
mRealm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
        @Override
        public void execute(Realm realm) {
            // Add a new FavoriteSong
            realm.copyToRealm(favoriteSong); // Fails with Value already exists: 0
        }
```

This fails because the Song contained in FavoriteSong already exists in the realm, violating the primary key constraint.

One solution is to set the FavoriteSong label as the primary key:

```
public class FavoriteSong extends RealmObject { 
    @Primary
    String label;
    Song song;
}
```

Then use copyToRealmOrUpdate() instead of copyToRealm(), which checks the primary key on all relationships before inserting:

```
realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(favoriteSong);
```

This works, but unfortunately I can't do it this way because there can be several FavoriteSongs with the same label, and the primary key won't allow that.

Any idea how I can add a FavoriteSong to the realm without the primary key, and without it failing the primary key constraint?

Comment: Does your `FavoriteSong` from the server contain a `song;`?

Comment: @EpicPandaForce - Yes

Comment: that is the source of your problem here: `FavoriteSong` does not have a primary key, but `copyToRealm()` will try to save the object inside it along with the fav song

Comment: Why don't you just add unique id to the `FavoriteSong` then? Use a `UUID.randomUUID()` for instance. That way you won't get duplicates.
Are `FavoriteSong`s unique for this specific user? I don't really understand the relationship between your models.

Comment: @Darwind - Yes, favorite songs are unique to this user, the server model for FavoriteSong has a "userId" field, but I don't feel it necessary to include that in my model since there is only one user. To elaborate on the relationship, we're using the "label" field of FavoriteSong as a category designator, so I can have multiple favorite songs with label "Classical" or "Hip-Hop". Might not be the best way of organizing but that's the way the back-end developers have decided to architect.

Comment: @EpicPandaForce - Yes, that is exactly the problem! I'll give your answer a whirl and see if I can get it to work.

Answer (score 1):

Please try

```
FavoriteSong favoriteSong = ...favorite song from server
mRealm.executeTransaction(new Realm.Transaction() {
        @Override
        public void execute(Realm realm) {
            Song tempSong = favoriteSong.getSong();
            favoriteSong.setSong(null);
            FavoriteSong savedFavoriteSong = realm.copyToRealm(favoriteSong);
            Song dbSong = realm.where(Song.class).equalTo(SongFields.ID, tempSong.getId()).findFirst();
            if(dbSong == null) {
                dbSong = realm.copyToRealmOrUpdate(tempSong);
            }
            savedFavoriteSong.setSong(dbSong);
        }
```

The `SongFields` is assuming you are using https://github.com/cmelchior/realmfieldnameshelper

Comment: Another soul saved by the EpicPanda ^^.

Comment: Ok, so I'm stupid, turns out what I'm looking for is trying to define a compound primary key with the label and the Song. Sorry for the confusion. This seems to be a popular topic with Realm, and I have a few questions that might be helpful for other user's. Can you give me a hand if I post another specific question about this?

Comment: Compound key means you should append the two properties together into a single String field.

Comment: Yes, at this point I'm trying to figure out where and when it would be most appropriate given my situation. Once I fetch my User object and save to the realm, I would at some point need to update the FavoriteSong compositeKey with the "label-songId". Is there a best practices for this or a callback on a realm object I can use for when it is created?

Comment: You just need to make sure you obtain the composite ID when you create the RealmObject in the Realm, because PK cannot be modified once object is created.

Comment: Gotcha, but is there a way to automate this when the object is added to the realm? I'm trying to avoid missing a call to set a composite key. For instance, I would have to create a composite key after I parse a User object from the server, and then also create a composite key when my user creates a new FavoriteSong and ads it to the server. Not a huge deal but I have a ton of relationships.

Comment: Then make an abstraction over your Realm access

Answer (score 0):

use

```
import io.realm.annotations.PrimaryKey;
```

instead of

```
import androidx.room.PrimaryKey;
```